# Entity Framework отмена изменений в локальной коллекции DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Здравствуйте. У меня есть таблица  которую я вытягиваю с помощью EF из БД и передаю во ViewModel для изменения (окно редактирования).
View отображает DataGrid, где байндинг осуществляется к полям сущности.
Внизу View (окно редактирования) 2 кнопки Сохранить и Выйти.
При нажатии на Сохранить вызываю команду Update и локальные данные сохраняются в БД. При нажатии на выход, просто закрываю окно.

При повторном открытии окна делаю команду Get но данные берутся не из БД а из локального хранилища. Т.е. измененные данные. Можно ли как-то отменить все локальные изменения?

Если на примере то вся проблема описывается так:

```
        //station.Name был равен Name1
        var station= _unitOfWork.StationRepository.Get().First();
        //поменяли в локальной коллекции без Update в БД
        station.Name = "NEWname";
        //сделали запрос чтобы к БД (хочу предыдущее состояние)
        station = _unitOfWork.StationRepository.Get().First();
        // но station.Name уже "NEWname";
```

Подскажите как лучше редактировать данные из БД?

код репозитория

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
{
    protected CisDbContext Context { get; }
    protected DbSet<TEntity> DbSet { get; }



    public GenericRepository(CisDbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();

    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> Get()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }
}
```

Скриншот производимых изменений во вложенной таблице (многие ко многим). Метод UndoChanges их не убирает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы данные не помещались в кэш, применяется метод `AsNoTracking()`. При его применении возвращаемые из запроса данные не кэшируются.

```
var station = _unitOfWork.StationRepository.Get().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
```

> Когда контекст данных извлекает данные из базы данных, Entity
>   Framework помещает извлеченные объекты в кэш и отслеживает изменения,
>   которые происходят с этими объектами вплоть до использования метода
>   `SaveChanges()`

Update

Если нужно сохранить изменения, то следует использовать метод `Attach()` и изменить состояние на `Modified`

```
using (var context = new myContext())
{
    var station= context.Station.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();

    station.Name = "New_Name";

    context.Station.Attach(station);
    context.Entry(station).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!! на простом примере работает. Но в моем сулчае AsNoTracking() приводит к исключению, при команде update. Сейчас напишу какое исключение.

Comment: ругается на DbSet.Attach(entity);

Comment: Attaching an entity of type 'Domain.Entities.Station'
failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.
This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' 
if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values.
In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Comment: @Aldmi у вас дублируется primary key, видимо вы пытаетесь добавить новый отредактированы объект у которого id такой же как и у предыдущего.

Comment: Да такое возникает при использовании AsNoTracking. Без него все нормально. А можно ли сбросить кэширование вызвав SaveChanges() без использования Update?

Answer (score 0):

Вот код который отменяет изменения внесённые после последнего вызова dbContext.SaveChanges().

```
public static void UndoChanges(this DbContext dbContext)
        {
            foreach (var entry in dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        entry.Reload();
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: этот метод расширения для контекста? и я должен вызывать его вручную когда хочу отменить изменения?

Comment: @Aldmi Да, все верное. Код в примере подправил.

Comment: Мне его лучше поместить в UnitOfWork чем в конкретный репозиторий, т.к. отменяются изменения всего контекста?

Comment: @Aldmi Ну это уже вам решать, все зависит от логики вашего кода. Я у себя использовал для отката изменений при исключений в SaveChanges().

Comment: На свойствах самой сущности работает, а коллекция вложенной сущности ICollection<OperativeSchedule> OperativeSchedules (связь многие ко многим) выбираю из списка OperativeSchedule, выбранный элемент так и остается. Может потому- что у меня не входит в контекст промежуточная таблица? и он не может отследить  изменения?

Comment: Я добавил скриншот того что я имею в виду при редактирвоании

Comment: Даже при связи 1 к 1, т.е. при изменении индекса ссылающегося на сущность из другой таблицы, изменения остаются. Может быть потому что я явно не определил FK в таблице?

Comment: @Aldmi Возможно вы разные DbContext  используете, для отката и для редактирования.

Comment: Да нет у меня один контекст, при редактировании связи 1 к 1 (т.е. выборе элемента из списка) и потом нажатие отмены в функцию UndoChanges не заходит. Если поменять родные поля (Имя например) то отмена работает отлично по ветке  case EntityState.Modified:

Comment: Сейчас без UI попробую поменять связь 1 к 1 (просто в коде) и потом отменить. если отмены не будет создам новое сообщение форума. Просто интересно как люди редактируют данные из БД в DataGrid например (базовые функции должны же быть сохранить изменения или отменить)